# How to understand Pratt Parsing

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

I'm reading Crafting Interpreters. It's very readable. Now I'm reading
chapter 17 Compiling Expressions and find algorithm:
Vaughan Pratt’s “top-down operator precedence parsing”. The implementation is very brief
and I don't understand it why it works.

So I read Vaughan Pratt’s “top-down operator precedence parsing” paper. It's so old
and not easy to read. I read related blogs about it and spend days reading the
original paper.
related blogs :

1. https://abarker.github.io/typped/pratt_parsing_intro.html
2. https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/03/19/pratt-parsers-expression-parsing-made-easy/
3. https://matklad.github.io/2020/04/13/simple-but-powerful-pratt-parsing.html

I am now more confident that I can write an implementation. But I still can't see the
trick behind the magic. Here are some of my questions, if I can describe them clealy:

1. What grammar can Pratt’s parser handle? Floyd Operator Grammar? I even take a look
   at Floyd's paper, but it's very abstract. Or  Pratt’s parser can handle any Language
   as long as it meets the  restrictions on page 44

> These restrictions on the language, while slightly irksome,...

2. On page 45,Theorem 2， Proof.

> First assign even integers (to make room for the followin~terpolations) to the data type classes.
> Then to each argument position assign an integer lying strictly (where possible) between the integers
> corresponding to the classes of the argument and result types.

On page 44,

> The idea is to assign data types to classes and then to totally order
> the classes.
> An example might be, in ascending order,Outcomes (e.g., the pseudo-result of “print”), Booleans,
> Graphs (e.g. trees, lists, plexes), Strings, Algebraics (e.g. integers, complex nos, polynomials)...

I can't figure out what the term "data type" means in this paper. If it means primitive
data types in a programming language, like boolean , int , char in Java, then the following exmaple
may be Counterexample

```
1 + 2 * 3
```

for +, it's argument type is number, say assign integer 2 to data type number class. +'s result data type is
also a number. so + must have the integer 2. But the same is for *. In this way + and * would have the same
binding power.

I guess data type in this paper is the AST Node type. So +'s result type is term, *'s result type is factor,
which will have a bigger integger than +'s. But I can't be sure.

Comment: Pratt parsing is not much different from shunting yard algorithm. It basically shifts operators and operands on the stack until a reduction is in order. The only difference in Pratt is that it uses the call stack for it. It can parse everything, but it works best for expressions.

Answer (score 2):

By data type, Pratt meant, roughly, "primitive data type in the programming language being parsed". (Although he included some things which are often not thought about as types, unless you program in C or C++, and I don't think he contemplated user-defined types.)

But Pratt is not really talking about a parsing algorithm on page 44. What he's talking about is language design. He wants languages to be designed in such a way that a simple semantic rule involving argument and result types can be used to determine operator precedence. He wants this rule, apparently, in order to save the programmer the task of memorizing arbitrary operator precedence tables (or to have to deal with different languages ordering operators in different ways.)

These are indeed laudable goals, but I'm afraid that the train had already left the station when Pratt was writing that paper. Half a century later, it's evident that we're never going to achieve that level of interlanguage consistency. Fortunately, we can always use parentheses, and we can even write compilers which nag at you about not using redundant parentheses until you give up and write them.

Anyway, that paragraph probably contravened SO's no-opinions policy, so let's get back to Pratt's paper. The rule he proposes is that all of a languages primitive datatypes be listed in a fixed total ordering, with the hope that all language designers will choose the same ordering. (I use the word "dominates" to describe this ordering: type A dominates another type B if A comes later in Pratt's list than B. A type does not dominate itself.)

At one end of the ordering is the `null` type, which is the result type of an operator which doesn't have a return value. Pratt calls this type "Outcome", since an operator which doesn't return anything must have had some side-effect --its "outcome"-- in order to not be pointless. At the other end of the ordering is what C++ calls a reference type: something which can be used as an argument to an assignment operator. And he then proposes a semantic rule: no operator can produce a result whose type dominates the type of one or more of its arguments, unless the operator's syntax unambiguously identifies the arguments.

That last exception is clearly necessary, since there will always be operators which produce types subordinate to the types of their arguments. Pratt's example is the `length` operator, which in his view must require parentheses because the Integer type dominates the String and Collection types, so `length x`, which returns an Integer given a String, cannot be legal. (You could write `length(x)` or `|x|` (provided `|` is not used for other purposes), because those syntaxes are unambiguous.)

It's worth noting that this rule must also apply to implicit coercions, which is equivalent to saying that the rule applies to all overloads of a single operator symbol. (C++ was still far in the future when Pratt was writing, but implicit coercions were common.)

Given that total ordering on types and the restriction (which Pratt calls "slightly irksome") on operator syntax, he then proposes a single simple syntactic rule: operator associativity is resolved by eliminating all possibilities which would violate type ordering. If that's not sufficient to resolve associativity, it can only be the case that there is only one type between the result and argument types of the two operators vying for precedence. In that case, associativity is to the left.

Pratt goes on to prove that this rule is sufficient to remove all ambiguity, and furthermore that it is possible to derive Floyd's operator precedence relation from type ordering (and the knowledge about return and argument types of every operator). So syntactically, Pratt's languages are similar to Floyd's operator precedence grammars.

But remember that Pratt is talking about language design, not parsing. (Up to that point of the paper.) Floyd, on the other hand, was only concerned with parsing, and his parsing model would certainly allow a prefix `length` operator. (See, for example, C's `sizeof` operator.) So the two models are not semantically equivalent.

This reduces the amount of memorization needed by someone learning the language: they only have to memorize the order of types. They don't need to try to memorize the precedence between, say, a concatenation operator and a division operator, because they can just work it out from the fact that Integer dominates String. [Note 1]

Unfortunately, Pratt has to deal with the fact that "left associative unless you have a type mismatch" really does not cover all the common expectations for expression parsing. Although not every language complies, most of us would be surprised to find that `a*4 + b*6` was parsed as `((a * 4) + b) * 6`, and would demand an explanation. So Pratt proposes that it is possible to make an exception by creating "pseudotypes". We can pretend that the argument and return types of multiplication and division are different from (and dominate) the argument and return types of addition and subtraction. Then we can allow the Product type to be implicitly coerced to the Sum type (conceptually, because the coercion does nothing), thereby forcing the desired parse.

Of course, he has now gone full circle: the programmer needs to memorise both the type ordering rules, but also the pseudotype ordering rules, which are nothing but precedence rules in disguise.

The rest of the paper describes the actual algorithm, which is quite clever. Although it is conceptually identical to Floyd's operator precedence parsing, Pratt's algorithm is a top-down algorithm; it uses the native call stack instead of requiring a separate stack algorithm, and it allows the parser to interpolate code with production parsing without waiting for the production to terminate.

I think I've already deviated sufficiently from SO's guidelines in the tone of this answer, so I'll leave it at that, with no other comment about the relative virtues of top-down and bottom-up control flows.

---

#### Notes

1. Integer dominates String means that there is no implicit coercion from a String to an Integer, the same reason that the length operator needs to be parenthesised. There could be an implicit coercion from Integer to String. So the expression `a divide b concatenate c` must be parsed as `(a divide b) concatenate c`. `a divide (b concatenate c)` is disallowed and so the parser can ignore the possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It eliminates a lot of my confusions. "it is conceptually identical to Floyd's operator precedence parsing", can I  understand it as Pratt parsing also parses (Operator-precedence_grammar) ? see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_grammar

Comment: @ChenLi: basically, yes. Any operator precedence grammar can be parsed. But since a Pratt parser is implemented as a computer program, it's not limited to following the theoretical model. Idiosyncratic exceptions can be inserted by hand into the code (and frequently are, as in the book you're currently reading).